# Poul Anderson novel about beaming humans to the stars with Dyson spheres, then returning after millennia

Tags: story-identification, novel, relativity

I'm trying to find a hard sci-fi novel; I think it's by Poul Anderson. The plot goes something like:

1. Humanity expands to the stars and builds Dyson Spheres so they can broadcast themselves and their culture to other planets.
2. An alien race who I *think* lives somewhere in the Virgo supercluster hears this broadcast, and manages to reconstruct humans from the DNA they receive. The story starts shortly afterwards.
3. The humans get tired of being effectively pets, and build a starship that travels at relativistic speeds back to the Milky Way, to try and discover their home planet. This of course takes thousands of years, but they experience it as fewer.
4. They get back to find the stars deserted and humanity gone. I don't quite remember what happens afterwards, but I think sentient rats have taken over the Earth and have started themselves expanding to the stars? Or maybe the rats are gone now too and now it's dragonflies? and there was some plot point that involved a space elevator, and a "storm" that sweeps across the Milky Way and wipes out all intelligent life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: It was a while ago, 8 years maybe? I don't remember the cover. I thought the title had "genesis" it it for some reason but Genesis by Poul Anderson has a completely different plot so that can't be it.

Comment: @fez yes, that's the same novel :)

Comment: @JoshuaNelson - thank you for confirming :)

Comment: I recall one tidbit that it mentions that the dragonfly nymphs had been genetically altered to never metamorphose, and so evolved from that form into human-sized killer bugs as the most recent top of the technological climb, and humans had evolved into some kind of small-ish monkey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot background of aliens reconstructing humans from DNA data transmitted to the Virgo cluster matches [*The Genesis Quest*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7508) (1986) by Donald Moffitt.  The title has "Genesis" in it, which matches your recollection

ISFDb gives this synopsis:

> Aliens receive radio signals containing full DNA info, and reconstruct humanity. This new humanity then grows up.

The plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Genesis_Quest) gives a bit more detail:

> An alien race (The Nar) assemble humans **from a stream of genetic information transmitted by radio** from the Milky Way Galaxy. The resulting colony of humans spend some time integrated into the Nar society before growing restless, discovering the secret of human longevity, and embarking on the seemingly impossible **millennia-long mission** of a physical journey back to Earth. This epic journey is made in a gigantic space-grown semi-sentient **Dyson tree** known as Yggdrasil.

I haven't read this, but it seems to match many of the details of your question.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/484984695) on Goodreads confirms that the original human signal was sent to the Virgo cluster.

Comment: omg this is it!!! thank you so much! the plot summary of the second book matches the plot points in 4. as well :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Genesis_(novel)